# Powershell: Using the Handle method of an Aggregate Exception in a Try/Catch block

Tags: .net, multithreading, powershell, powershell-4.0

I have a task that performs a reverse DNS lookup of about 50-60 possible devices.  In no instance will there ever be no aggregate exception thrown.

What I have seems to work if you go just by the console output (no red text), but the exception can still be found in the $Error variable.

I've been unable to find an example of using the Handle method in PowerShell so far.

I'm going off the examples obtained from the following link, but I'm not very familiar with C# or VB. I may be having an issue with translation into PowerShell.

https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.aggregateexception.handle(v=vs.110).aspx?cs-save-lang=1&cs-lang=vb#code-snippet-3

What I'm wondering is... Where did I go wrong, or is the exception actually handled?

Below is the code that should demonstrate the reason for my quandary. It will create a task made up of 3 asynchronous reverse DNS lookups that should fail. Calling WaitAll should produce the expected aggregate exceptions and appear to be handled, but are still observed in $Error.

```
$Task = @('testComp1','testComp2','testComp3') | ForEach-Object {
    [pscustomobject]@{
        Computername = $_
        Task = [System.Net.DNS]::GetHostAddressesAsync($_)
    }
}

try
{
    [Void][Threading.Tasks.Task]::WaitAll($Task.Task)
}

catch [System.AggregateException]
{
    $_.Exception.Handle({
        param($ex)

        if ( $ex.GetType().Name -eq 'SocketException' ) {
            Write-Host 'Expected SocketException'
            return $true
        } else {
            return $false
        }
    })
}

$Error[0]
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is no relation with `$Error`.

The `Handle` method acts like a filter on the exceptions within the `AggregateException`.
The exceptions for which the predicate has returned false, end up in a new `AggregateException` that will be thrown.

See the remarks on [MSDN](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.aggregateexception.handle?view=netframework-4.7.1).

> Each invocation of the predicate returns true or false to indicate
>   whether the Exception was handled. After all invocations, if any
>   exceptions went unhandled, all unhandled exceptions will be put into a
>   new AggregateException which will be thrown.

**An Example.**

Here below an `AggregateException` containing a `DivideByZeroException` and an `IndexOutOfRangeException` gets thrown.
Notice that the first `catch` block shows 2 inner exceptions (#0 and #1).
Only the `IndexOutOfRangeException` gets handled.

This results in a new `AggregateException` being thrown, but this time containing only the `DivideByZeroException`.
Notice that the second `catch` block shows only 1 inner exception.

```
try
{
    try
    {
        $divideByZeroException = (New-Object -TypeName System.DivideByZeroException)
        $indexOutOfRangeException = (New-Object -TypeName System.IndexOutOfRangeException)
        throw (New-Object -TypeName System.AggregateException -ArgumentList $divideByZeroException,$indexOutOfRangeException)
    }
    catch [System.AggregateException]
    {        
        $_.Exception.ToString() | out-host

        # System.AggregateException: One or more errors occurred. ---> System.DivideByZeroException: Attempted to divide by zero.
        # --- End of inner exception stack trace ---
        # ---> (Inner Exception #0) System.DivideByZeroException: Attempted to divide by zero.<---
        # ---> (Inner Exception #1) System.IndexOutOfRangeException: Index was outside the bounds of the array.<---

        $_.Exception.Handle({
            param($ex)

            if ($ex.GetType().Name -eq 'IndexOutOfRangeException' ) {                
                return $true
            } else {             
                return $false
            }
        })
    }
}
catch [System.AggregateException]
{    
    $_.Exception.ToString() | out-host

    # System.AggregateException: One or more errors occurred. --->         System.DivideByZeroException: Attempted to divide by zero.
    # --- End of inner exception stack trace ---
    #  at System.AggregateException.Handle(Func`2 predicate)
    #   at CallSite.Target(Closure , CallSite , Object , ScriptBlock )
    #---> (Inner Exception #0) System.DivideByZeroException: Attempted to divide by zero.<---
}
```

Comment: Thanks! I just wanted confirmation as it was still in $Error.