# Run SQL query against Azure SQL database using PowerShell

Tags: sql-server, azure, powershell

My task is to retrieve the users list from our Azure SQL databases. We have 100s of Azure SQL database and I want to use PowerShell to make the task fast.

I am using connection string (Active Directory Integrated). I believe I am able to login to the SQL database using the connection string with PowerShell.

However, I am getting an error while running the SQL. Below is the code and exception. Could you please help me?

Code:

```
try {
    $new = 'Server=tcp:dummy.database.windows.net,1433;Authentication="Active Directory Integrated";Initial Catalog=xtoiteuitbdbsqldb01;Persist Security Info=False;MultipleActiveResultSets=False;Encrypt=True;TrustServerCertificate=False;'
    $sql = "SELECT * FROM sys.database_principals"
  $temp_result_object = invoke-sqlcmd -ConnectionString $new -Query $sql
} catch {
  "error when running sql $sql"
  write-host "Exception type: $($_.Exception.GetType().FullName)" -ForegroundColor Red
    write-host "Exception message: $($_.Exception.Message)" -ForegroundColor Red
    write-host "Error: " $_.Exception -ForegroundColor Red   
}
```

Exception:

> Exception type: ManagedBatchParser.ParserException
>   Exception message:
>   Error:  ManagedBatchParser.ParserException
>
> at ManagedBatchParser.Parser.Parse()
>   at Microsoft.SqlServer.Management.PowerShell.ExecutionProcessor.ExecuteTSql(String sqlCommand)

Comment: Are you using `Invoke-SqlCmd` from the `SQLPS` module? I don't believe it has a `-ConnectionString` parameter. Try `Get-Help Invoke-SqlCmd`.

Comment: I checked the Help file and it does not contain "-connectionString".  What do I use?

Comment: Rather than constructing a single connection string make use of the individual `-Server`, `-ServerInstance` and `-Database` parameters. It's just a wrapper around the `sqlcmd.exe` command line tool so can basically do (most of) whatever that tool can do.

Comment: I am connecting to Azure sql database (PaaS offering). The idea is to connect to the Azure SQL Database using the connection string that has Active Directory Integration provided my Microsoft Azure to by pass providing UserID and Password.

Comment: If you're stuck with Azure AD Authentication then I think you cannot use the `Invoke-SqlCmd` PowerShell cmdlet. You'll have to use the `sqlcmd.exe` tool directly so you can use its `[-G use Azure Active Directory for authentication]` parameter, which the `Invoke-SqlCmd` cmdlet doesn't expose. See [Azure AD token - sqlcmd](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/sql-database/sql-database-aad-authentication-configure#azure-ad-token) for an example.

Answer (score 15):

The below worked for me, Connect-AzAccount triggers interactive AAD auth via the browser

[Example 11: Connect to Azure SQL Database (or Managed Instance) using an Access Token](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/sqlserver/invoke-sqlcmd?view=sqlserver-ps&source=docs#example-11--connect-to-azure-sql-database--or-managed-instance--using-an-access-token)

```
Import-Module SQLServer
Import-Module Az.Accounts -MinimumVersion 2.2.0

# Note: the sample assumes that you or your DBA configured the server to accept connections using
#       that Service Principal and has granted it access to the database (in this example at least
#       the SELECT permission).

### Obtain the Access Token: this will bring up the login dialog
Connect-AzAccount
$access_token = (Get-AzAccessToken -ResourceUrl https://database.windows.net).Token

# Now that we have the token, we use it to connect to the database 'mydb' on server 'myserver'
Invoke-Sqlcmd -ServerInstance myserver.database.windows.net -Database mydb -AccessToken $access_token`
              -query 'select * from Table1'
```

Alternatively get a Managed Identity access token ([source](https://joonasw.net/view/get-managed-identity-access-token-in-azure-app-service-through-kudu))

```
$resource = "https://database.windows.net"
$endpoint = $env:IDENTITY_ENDPOINT
$header = $env:IDENTITY_HEADER
$apiVersion = "2019-08-01"

$headers = @{ 'X-Identity-Header' = $header }

$url = "$($endpoint)?api-version=$apiVersion&resource=$resource"

$response = Invoke-RestMethod -Method Get -Uri $url -Headers $headers
$response.access_token
```

Comment: This definitely worked for me. I'd mark it as an Answer if I could...

Comment: I am trying Invoke-Sqlcmd and is not working for me, get an error establishing connection to sql server. I have entra auth enabled for the managed instance and admin is an entra group which has my service principal added. I try to execute in cloud shell and see the same issue. Any suggestions?

Answer (score 3):

You can use the .NET `SqlClient` provider in order to use either password or "Active Directory Integrated" authentication, e.g.:

```
# connect to database
$dbConn = New-Object System.Data.SqlClient.SqlConnection
$dbConn.ConnectionString = "Server=tcp:dummy.database.windows.net,1433;Database=DummyDB;Authentication=Active Directory Integrated;Encrypt=True;"
$dbConn.Open()

# construct command
$dbCmd = New-Object System.Data.SqlClient.SqlCommand
$dbCmd.Connection = $dbConn
$dbCmd.CommandText = "SELECT * FROM sys.database_principals"

# fetch all results
$dataset = New-Object System.Data.DataSet
$adapter = New-Object System.Data.SqlClient.SqlDataAdapter
$adapter.SelectCommand = $dbCmd
$adapter.Fill($dataset)

# display results
$dataset.Tables | Format-Table
```

Comment: I get this exception: Exception calling "Open" with "0" argument(s): "One or more errors occurred."
At X  $dbConn.Open()
+ ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
    + CategoryInfo          : NotSpecified: (:) [], MethodInvocationException
    + FullyQualifiedErrorId : AggregateException
 
Exception calling "Fill" with "1" argument(s): "One or more errors occurred."
At x
+ $adapter.Fill($dataset)
+ ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
    + CategoryInfo          : NotSpecified: (:) [], MethodInvocationException
    + FullyQualifiedErrorId : AggregateException

Comment: Hmmm, it may be a connection/permissions issue, but you'll need to drill down into that AggregateException to see what the underlying error is.  This answer shows an example of dealing with AggregateExceptions: https://stackoverflow.com/a/50804912/8626917

Comment: I also got the same error and could never get any more detailed info on it.

Answer (score -1):

Try something like below and see if it helps:

```
$Svr = "SVR"
$SvrPort = 10003
$Username = "ABC\sql"
$Password = "ABC#@!"

$Password = $Password | ConvertTo-SecureString -AsPlainText -Force
$Cred = New-Object System.Management.Automation.PSCredential -ArgumentList $Username,$Password
$Inst = $Svr + "," + $SvrPort

Get-PSSession

New-PSSession -ComputerName $Svr -Credential $Cred

Invoke-Sqlcmd -ServerInstance $Inst -Database "master" -Query "SELECT @@SERVERNAME AS SERVER_NAME"

Get-PSSession

Get-PSSession | Remove-PSSession

Invoke-Sqlcmd -ServerInstance $Inst -Database "master" -Query "SELECT @@SERVERNAME AS SERVER_NAME"

Get-PSSession
```

Also refer to below post for further reference:

[Active Directory Password Connection Azure SQL Failure from Azure Automation](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45091135/active-directory-password-connection-azure-sql-failure-from-azure-automation?rq=1)

Comment: We do not want to use username and password. We want to use the "Active Directory Integration" option from the ADO.NET connection string.

Comment: Manjunath - see golfalot's post above.